# The modulus of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$\def\Im{\mathrm{Im}}$Let $a,z,a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in \mathbb {C}$ such that $\Im(a_1),\Im(a_2),\cdots,\Im(a_n) $ have the same sign and $$a(z+a_1)(z+a_2)\cdots(z+a_n)+(z+\overline a_1)(z+\overline a_2)\cdots(z+\overline a_n)=0.$$
Prove that $z\in \mathbb{R}$ only and only if $|a|=1$.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Maybe look at the $n=2,3$ cases?

Comment: As you can see from other posts of yours, if no efforts are showed by the OP, the question is prone to being closed or downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is easy:

We have
$$a\prod_{i=1}^n(z+a_i)=-\prod_{i=1}^n(z+\bar{a_i}). $$
Taking norm:
$$|a|\prod_{i=1}^n|z+a_i|=\prod_{i=1}^n|z+\bar{a_i}|. $$
Now if $z$ is real, then $|z+a_i|=|\overline{z+a_i}|=|z+\bar{a_i}|$ thus $|a|=1$.

For other direction, I have no idea!

Comment: Thank you, but i made the first direction to..